# How can I have a camera on a defined part of the screen on iPhone 4/4S?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera, avfoundation

I am using the AVFoundation framework to have a camera view on my iPhone app.

On iPhone 5 and further, the camera fills the entire view where it's in. On iPhone 4/4S, the view isn't filled entirely and I get blank spaces on both sides of the view. I believe it's not because of the constraints, but because of the proportion of the iPhone's screen :

With the preset `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`, on iPhone 5/6, the ratio of the image is 3/4. On iPhone 4/4S with the same preset, the ratio of the image is 9/16. It looks like the shape of my camera's view can be filled with a 3/4 image, not a 9/16 image.

So I looked for all the preset available, and I tried the preset `AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480` thinking that the problem would be solved since 640*480 delivers a 3/4 image... But it didn't fixed anything, I still have blank spaces on both sides of the view.

Is there a way to adapt the resolution with the AVFoundation framework ?

(I think my problem would be easier to understand with images, but I'm not authorized to post some yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found a way to use the camera on the exact ratio i wanted, so I just created a new ViewController that I only use on the iPhone 4/4S, with a different interface for this device